# Global Server Load Balancing for OpenVPN over OpenVPN with DSR

Tags: networking, linux-networking, openvpn, load-balancing, ipvs

Ok, so...I am in no sense a pro when it comes to networks, load balancing, tunneling or VPN connections BUT I tried a few things to get this theoretical concept to work - obviously without success.

What I try to achieve: Create a public VPN (so open for external connections from the Internet), have the clients connect to a load balancer server that then forwards the traffic based on least connections to the backend servers that are not in the same network and only accessible via Internet (no, there is no way to change this unfortunately) and have them respond directly to the client (DSR) so that the bandwidth occurs mainly on the backend nodes and not on the load balancer so that there is no bottleneck on the load balancer.

So my idea was: Since our hoster does not offer private networks I need to remotely connect multiple servers for load balancing together. Therefore for testing purposes I created:

- A load balancer server which also functions as the internal VPN server to create the network I figured is needed to connect the servers privately and put them on the same subnet
- A first external VPN server node which is "behind" the load balancer server in the sense that I want to connect to the load balancer and then get the traffic forwarded to one of the nodes using "least connections" and then have the node directly connect to the client (Direct Server Return) in order to not have all the bandwidth occur on the loadbalancer again
- A virtual IP (10.8.0.250)

After successfully creating the VPN and connecting the node to it, I have the following IPs:

```
10.8.0.1 (Load Balancer and internal VPN Server)
10.8.0.10 (First external VPN Server node)
```

On the Load Balancer I enabled IP forwarding, created the following DNAT entry:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp --dport 1194 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.250
```

and the following IPVS entry:

```
ipvsadm -A -u 10.8.0.250:1194 -s wlc
ipvsadm -a -u 10.8.0.250:1194 -r 10.8.0.10:1194 -g -w 1
```

I also added the virtual IP to the loopback interface of the external VPN Server node so that it would accept the traffic coming in for the virtual IP.

That's basically what I did and it does not work.

Now my question is: Is there any chance this works at all or am I simply trying something that is impossible in the way I do it?
And if so: What would be the best way to do this given that the servers will only be connected through the Internet and there is no way to group them together on the same private network.

Thanks in advance for any hints!

Comment: `What would be the best way to do this` the "best" way is using the market leading products. You're essentially looking at a (probably minimal) subset of features. Reviewing how other products do it  may be useful when piecing something together. https://aws.amazon.com/global-accelerator/ https://www.f5.com/pdf/products/big-ip-global-traffic-manager-ds.pdf